# In cnosdb, I want to know how to use non-root users to create and delete other users?

Tags: cnosdb

When I'm using cnosdb，I created tenant A and user A, and assigned the owner role of tenant A to user A, but I found that I could not use User A to create and delete other users. Is there any way to solve this problem?